# SQL value = 0.5 or 0.0

Tags: sql, floor

I have a floor question.

(1) -

```
declare @value numeric(5,1),
set @value = 36.66,
select floor(2*@value)/2,
Answer= 36.5
```

But
(2) -

```
declare @value numeric(5,1),
set @value = 110/3,
select floor(2*@value)/2,
Answer = 36
```

I need the answer = 36.5 and user (2)

Thanks

Comment: try set @value = 110/3.0 or 110.0/3, probably a problem of integer division.

Comment: Why are you assigning a value with two decimal places to a variable with datatype `numeric(5,1)`?

Comment: Which database system do you use? Please add the appropriate tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

110/3 - those are integer values and the result returned will be integer, so it automatically casts to integer, making the value 36 :)

So in the second case your `floor` is doing nothing.